# problem of onglet (tagPage) iteration : c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I would iterative a `TabPage` and a `WebBrowser` controls.

I want to add a new webBrowser in a new Tab after each click. But I've got this error message :

> Impossible to fix the index [] to this control-object

the code is the following :

```
TabPage var_i = new TabPage();
webBrowser webBrowser = new webBrowser();
int i = 0;

private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser[i].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(var_i[i]);
    var_i[i].Controls.Add(webBrowser[i]);
    i++;
        
    if (textBox1_url.Text != "")
    {
        webBrowser[i].Navigate(textBox1_url.Text);
        var_i[i].Text = textBox1_url.Text;
    }
}
```

thanks you for your contribution.

M.A.

Comment: Your `var_i` is a `TabPage`, so you can't access `var_i[i]` (it is not a collection of items)

Comment: how can I used a collection of items associated to a tabPage iteration ?

Comment: Your `TabPage` is 1 item. `tabControl1.TabPages` seems to be a collection of `TabPage`s, are you looking for this?

Comment: I would advice adding a control to the first and second tabs using the Visual Studio designer and looking at the Form1.designer.cs file to understand how does it work.

Comment: I would to have a collection of tabPage using a loop or an iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I used the function "AddRange" to the control TabControl and add a new value of tab collection.

```
tabcontrol1.Controls.AddRange(new Control [] { this.tabPage1 };
```

Comment: Wouldn't `tabcontrol1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);` do the same? I don't understand why you feel the need to add a collection made from 1 item, when you can directly add the item in question